# How do I dismiss a WKInterfaceController that was presented with contextForSegue?

Tags: watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacecontroller

I have a `WKInterfaceController` with a `WKInterfaceTable` that lists some events a user has recorded in my app.

A user can tap a row of the table to see more details about that event. To accomplish this, I've overridden `contextForSegue(withIdentifier:in:rowIndex:)` on the `WKInterfaceController` that contains the table, so tapping a row modally presents a detail view of that row in a new `WKInterfaceController` called `EventDetailController`.

The `modal` presentation is defined on the Storyboard. I can't use `push` presentation because the `WKInterfaceController` with the `WKInterfaceTable` is a page among multiple instances of `WKInterfaceController` at the top level of my app.

### Here's the main issue:

Within the `EventDetailController`, there's a **Delete** button to destroy the record that the table row represents.

When a user taps the **Delete** button, I present an alert that allows the user to confirm or cancel the delete action.

Once the user confirms the record deletion, I want to dismiss the `EventDetailController` since it's no longer relevant, because it represents a deleted record.

Here's the `IBAction` defined on `EventDetailController` that gets called when the **Delete** button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(_ sender: WKInterfaceButton) {

    let deleteAction = WKAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) {

        // delete the record

        // as long as the delete was successful, dismiss the detail view
        self.dismiss()
    }

    let cancelAction = WKAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
        // do nothing
    }

    presentAlert(withTitle: "Delete Event",
                 message: "Are you sure you want to delete this event?",
                 preferredStyle: .alert,
                 actions: [deleteAction, cancelAction])
}
```

The problem is that watchOS doesn't seem to allow this. When testing this code, the `EventDetailController` does not dismiss. Instead, an error message is logged in the console:

`[WKInterfaceController dismissController]:434: calling dismissController from a WKAlertAction's handler is not valid. Called on <Watch_Extension.EventDetailController: 0x7d1cdb90>. Ignoring`

I've tried some weird workarounds to try to trick the `EventDetailController` into dismissing, like firing a notification when the event is deleted and dismissing the `EventDetailController` from a function that's called from an observer of the notification, but that doesn't work either.

At this point I'm thinking there's some correct way I'm supposed to be able to dismiss a `WKInterfaceController`, or in other words reverse the `contextForSegue(withIdentifier:in:rowIndex:)` call, but I don't know what it is.

When I call `dismiss()` directly in the `IBAction`, instead of in a `WKAlertAction` handler, it works fine, but I don't like this implementation since it doesn't allow the user to confirm the action first.

Answer (score 7):

I feel like an idiot, but I figured out the solution.

The answer was in Apple's `WKInterfaceController.dismiss()` documentation the whole time (emphasis added):

> Call this method when you want to dismiss an interface controller that you presented modally. **Always call this method from your WatchKit extension’s main thread.**

All I had to do differently was call `self.dismiss()` on the main thread.

Here's my updated code for the delete action, which now works as expected:

```
let deleteAction = WKAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) {

    // delete the record

    // as long as the delete was successful, dismiss the detail view
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will save someone else some troubleshooting time!

Comment: We had some similar code working fine on watchOS4 which was broken on watchOS5. Adding this solved it for us:
`DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dismiss()
    }`

Comment: Thank you, saved me some time. Also Apple at least could crash the .dismiss() code when it is not called on main thread (like it does in many other cases).